# can anyone tell me why the first twoSum logic returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me why the first twoSum logic returns undefined?

```html
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    const cache = {};
    for (let i=0 ;i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (cache[nums[i]]) {
            return [cache[nums[i]], i];
        }
        cache[target - nums[i]] = i
    }
};

const twoSum = (nums, target)  => {
    let hash = {}
    
    for (let i = 0; i< nums.length; i++ ) {
        if(hash[nums[i]] !== undefined) {
            return [hash[nums[i]], i];
        }
        hash[target - nums[i]] = i
    }
};
```

Comment: Most likely because `if (cache[nums[i]])` is `false` if the value is `0`.

Comment: you are right lol.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

---

### Two Sum

---

> *Two Sum Brute force and Hash Table solutions found in snippet below*

**Quick Answer:** Looks like your index key might be off (or trying to find an index that doesn't exist)

This example is completed in the bottom snippet and works using the hash_table approach to solving two sum that you're using above.

```js
            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
             |     TwoSum HashTable Approach ~ How It Works ~ Step By Step
             *------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | 
             |   . Input
             |     -> number = 9 (target sum)
             |     -> items = [6,3,4,53,23,4,5]
             |
             |   . Loop 1
             |     -> sum = 9
             |     -> number = 6
             |     -> difference = 3. 
             |     -> We set mapping[6] = 0 (if we find a 3, it's difference will be 6)
             |     -> When we check mapping[difference, we don't have a 3 mapped yet
             | 
             |
             |   . Loop 2
             |     -> sum = 9
             |     -> number = 3
             |     -> difference = 6
             |     -> We set mapping[3] = 1
             |     -> When we check for mapping[difference], we have it from Loop 1
             |     -> We return [difference, number]
             |     
             */
                     
      let twoSumHashTableApproach(items = [], number) => {
         let mapping = {}
    
         items.forEach((number, index) => {
            mapping[number] = index
            let difference = sum - number

            if (mapping[difference]) {
              return [difference, number]
            }
          })

         // no sums found, return -1 -1 
         return [-1, -1]
      }
}
```

---

#### Four Approaches to Solving Two Sum Problems

---

- **Brute force Approach:**

  - loop inside a loop
  - O(n^2) Time complexity
  - Example in bottom code snippet
- **Binary Search Approach:**

  - Sort items
  - Determine what number you need
  - Grab from somewhere in the middle of the list
  - If your value is higher than middle value, take right side and repeat
  - If your value is lower than middle value, take left side and repeat
  - If your value is the middle value, you have your solution
  - O(n log n) time complexity
- **Two pointers Approach:**

  - find index 0
  - find last index
  - start looping while (left < right)
  - increment left pointer
  - increment right pointer down
  - O(n) time complexity

```js
    let left = 0; 
    let right = items.length - 1

    while (left < right)
    {
       // logic goes here if (sum = items[left] + items[right])

   
       // left++
       // right--
    }
```

- **Hash Table/Dictionary/Map Approach**

  - create a hash table (just a simple object in js)
  - dictionary[number] = index
  - difference = sum - number
  - if (dictionary[number] && dictionary[difference]) return [number, difference]
  - O(n) time complexity and space complexity
  - Example of this approach shown in bottom snippet

```js
let TwoSum = {
    brute: (numbers = [], sum) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            for (let j = i+1; j < numbers.length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] === sum) {
                    // return [i, j] // indexes of sum 
                    // return [numbers[i], numbers[j]] // numbers of sum
                    return [{ index: i, value: numbers[i] }, {index: j, value: numbers[j]}]
                }
            }
        }

        return [-1, -1]
    },
    
    hash_table: (numbers = [], sum) => {
        let mapping = {}
        let differences = new Set()
        
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            let number = numbers[i]
            let difference = sum - number
            
            mapping[number] = i
            
            
            if (mapping[difference]) {
                // return [mapping[difference], mapping[number]] // indeces of two items with values equaling the sum

                // return [difference, number] // values of of the two items with values equaling the sum

                 return [{ index: mapping[difference], value: difference }, { index: mapping[number], value: number }] 
            }
        }

        return [-1, -1]
    }
}

let target = 9
let items = [0,4,2,3,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,6,7,2,3]
console.log("--------------------------------")
console.log("Two Sum Brute Force")
console.log("--------------------------------")
console.log(TwoSum.brute(items, 9))
console.log("--------------------------------")
console.log("Two Sum Hash Table/Mapping")
console.log("--------------------------------")
console.log(TwoSum.hash_table(items, 9))
```